# How to position (use H to place here) table and figures in elsevier cas latex template?

Tags: tables, floats, positioning, els-cas

I am using elsevier cas single column latex template and want to position figures and tables using H option, but I get error "Kernel/Key unknown" and "The module does not have a key called cas/tbl/H or cas/fig/H". I have used float package in the document preamble. How can I position figures and tables?

Comment: The [H] option is provided by the float package, and is not recommended.  [ht] provides a backup plan if [h] doesn't work.  I don't recall if elsevier has any additional restrictions placed on floats.

Comment: I am unable to use any of the H, h, or, ht etc. Every time I get the error "The module does not have a key called cas/fig/ht"

Comment: It sounds like a coding error.  Please provide a Minimal Working Example which demonstrates the error.

Comment: It would be best if you can supply a minimal example that shows your current setup. See [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764)

Comment: I wrote \begin{figure}[pos=b] and it works. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

The answer is, use pos=h instead of h or ht directly.

Meaning: `\begin{table}[pos=h]` instead of `\begin{table}[h]`

Comment: pos=h will still allow it to float. I have been able to use pos=H with \usepackage{float} to get it to force a figure where I want and compile without errors. simply using [H] will result in an error.